# Keep USB C & HDMI plugged into Dell Monitor all the time?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, power

I have the Dell U2327QE monitor, and I use it for both Mac and Windows. It's some work every time to plug the HDMI or USB-C into the monitor, instead I want to keep both cables plugged into the monitor while plugging the one I want to work with into the computer I choose to work with: mac or windows, is this something people do or highly unadvised? What harm would do that to the monitor or to the cables?

Comment: You could use a Docking Station to reduce the number of cables to replug ([example](https://www.amazon.com/Docking-Station-Monitor-1000Mbps-Multiport/dp/B0B1PT5FVM/ref=sr_1_3?crid=34NN8HCVXNXBD&keywords=dock+usb+c+hdmi&qid=1698591195&sprefix=dock+usb+c+hdmi%2Caps%2C155&sr=8-3)). Is that a solution?

Comment: I already have that, but I only have two cables so no big deal. The dock is for my mac, my monitor has a hub integrated in it. But that was not my question :) My question is about safety

Answer (score 0):

There should be no electrical harm to monitor, as I presume that you
are not (un)plugging the cable on the monitor's side.

As regarding USB-C ports, they are generally durable and not
easily damaged. Most are rated for more than 10,000 times.
This means that if you insert or remove your cable three times a day,
it would last for more than 9 years.
You would likely replace your computer before that happens.

HDMI are usually rated for somewhat less, but should last for years if
(un)plugged straight and without using force.
If worried, you could get an HDMI Switch Splitter that supports
2 connections in and 1 Out
([example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K2NZX8L)).

In most cases, if the (un)plug is done carefully, the cable is likely
to wear out before the port, and is easily replaced.

Comment: But you answered the opposite of my question, my question is about keeping these cables plugged into my monitor, not un-plugging them many times.

Comment: This is what I assumed - that you (un)plug on the computer(s) side. My answer probably applies to both sides.

Comment: Yeah, applies to both sides, thanks anyways